# CSS - How to overwrite the width size of class

Tags: css

Code:

```
<div id="pagewrap">
   <div id="test">
      asdf asdf asdf
   </div>
</div>
```

Let say the 'pagewrap' id has fixed width of 980px css, but I want the `test` id to have full width of the screen which is bigger than 980px.
By using CSS, is this possible?

Comment: @Vdt `!important` wont work here

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute;` for making your child div as 100%;

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3V3Z9/1/)

CSS

```
#pagewrap {
    width: 980px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

#test {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Haha -1 vooo please let me know what's wrong

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. Resize the result portion of your jsFiddle to see what I mean. The div is 960px wide, no more. (hint, don't use `position: relative;`)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha ya but you can certainly move that div out :)

Comment: That's not what the OP requested. OP requested the inner div to be 100% of the viewport. Your answer fails at that fundamental criterion, hence, the downvote. Fix your answer, and I shall remove it. That's all there is to it, it's not personal.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha ok thanks I'll fix it soon

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thanks for pointing it out, fixed my answer as well as the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You could also give the `#test` an `position:absolute` and make it `width:100%`

made a little jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/MAAaD/

Comment: now what makes this answer different than mine

Comment: @Mr.Alien: This one works. (Hint, he didn't give `position: relative;` to the parent)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha already fixed it, I was in a way that child div shouldn't flow out in the wild so gave position relative ;)

Comment: Thanks! I have an issue though. I have more DIV than the example above and one of the div contains 'relative' so it's displaying not properly. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions, listed from best to worst.

1. Give it `position: absolute` and `width: 100%`. (Much like mr.alex has stated before I did).
2. Pull it out of its parent div, and use `width: 100%`. (Which may hinder semantics, but works well if you want to use it as a dialogue or something).
3. Use JavaScript. (Only if you have a very good reason to not use either of the answers above).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#pagewrap #test {
   width: 1000px !important;
}
```

Comment: How is 1000px === the width of the viewport?

Comment: 1000px is a sample width. You can make it in % also. For example
width: 100% !important;

Answer (score -2):

try to use 100% width. that covers the complete size of the parent tag.

```
width:100%
```

Comment: make the position of #test as absolute. it works.